# How do I use two different images, one as a thumbnail and one as a linked image?

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to do an image gallery in a post, where the linked image (a href) was different from the thumbnail's src. Unfortunately, WP seems completely incapable of doing this.
Is there any solution or plugin?

Answer (score 2):

This plugin is what you need:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-featured-images/

Comment: In my gallery are more than one images, so it isn't my solution

Comment: ohh, did you take a look at nextgen gallery? Don't know if it works

Comment: yeah, I use nextgen gallery but it use same image for thumbnail and only crop its

Comment: Well Then I would say you have to code something yourself

Comment: can you code? because then you could make it yourself